# Symfony Apache External Redirections

Tags: php, apache, symfony, url, redirect

I've done a URL shortener app for my server side programming subject.
For fun I decided to deploy it on a web server, in this case the oracle free tier with an ubuntu server with apache, and I also adquired a public domain.

In my local environment all works fine using the symfony local server:

```
symfony server:start
```

But once I deployed the app the redirections doesn't work anymore.

All occur on the home page, the user types the URL to shortener( and the new 'endpoint'), Symfony validates the URL and if it's the case the new 'endpoint', then if all it's valid store the data and also in the home shows the new URL (ex. '/hjas8ab') that the user needs to paste it behind my domain (ex. mydomain.xyz/hjas8ab) and then Symfony checks that the 'endpoint' is associated to an URL in the database and redirects the user to that URL. And is in this step that the app deployed fails, even if I hardcode the URL to redirect.

So I think it's the Apache virtual host configuration, but I'm not sure.

Here is the code:

- ShortenerController.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ShortenerController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/{url?}', name: 'shortener')]
    public function index(?String $created, ?String $endpoint,?bool $autogenerated, ?String $url, Request $req): Response
    {   

        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET" && !is_null($url) ){
            return $this->forward('App\Controller\UrlAddressController::redirection', ['finalRedirection' => $url]);
        }

        if(!is_null($endpoint)){
            return $this->render('shortener/index.html.twig', [
                'created' => $created, 'endpoint' => $endpoint, 'autogenerated' => $autogenerated
            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('shortener/index.html.twig');
    }

    #[Route('/create/autogenerated', name: 'autogenerated')]
    public function autogenerated(Request $req): Response
    {   
        define('URL_PATTERN', "/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)(:[0-9]{0,5})?(#[\w]*)?((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)/i");

        $urlOriginal = $req->request->get('url');

        $validUrl = preg_match(URL_PATTERN, $urlOriginal);

        if($validUrl !== 1){
            return $this->render('shortener/index.html.twig', ['invalidAutogenerated'=> 'La URL introducida no es valida.']);
        }

        $autogeneratedURL = bin2hex(random_bytes(6));


        return $this->forward('App\Controller\UrlAddressController::createUrlAddress', ['urlEndpoint' => $autogeneratedURL, 'realUrl' => $urlOriginal, 'autogenerated' => true]);
    }

    #[Route('/create/custom', name: 'custom')]
    public function custom(Request $req): Response
    {   
        define('URL_PATTERN', "/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)(:[0-9]{0,5})?(#[\w]*)?((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)/i");

        define('ENDPOINT_PATTERN', "/^[A-Za-z0-9]{7,15}$/i");

        $urlOriginal = $req->request->get('urlCustom');

        $nuevaUrl = $req->request->get('endpoint');

        $validUrl = preg_match(URL_PATTERN, $urlOriginal);


        $validEndpoint = preg_match(ENDPOINT_PATTERN, $nuevaUrl);

        if($validUrl !== 1){
            return $this->render('shortener/index.html.twig', ['invalidCustom'=> 'La URL introducida no es valida.']);
        }

        if($validEndpoint !== 1){
            return $this->render('shortener/index.html.twig', ['invalidEndPoint'=> 'La URL introducida no es valida. Solo caracteres alfanuméricos.']);
        }

        return $this->forward('App\Controller\UrlAddressController::createUrlAddress', ['urlEndpoint' => $nuevaUrl, 'realUrl' => $urlOriginal, 'autogenerated' => 0]);
    }
}
```

- UrlAddressController.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\UrlAddress;
use App\Repository\UrlAddressRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class UrlAddressController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/urlAddress', name: 'url_address')]
    public function createUrlAddress(ManagerRegistry $doctrine, String $urlEndpoint, String $realUrl, bool $autogenerated): Response
    {   
        $created = '';

        $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();

        $newUrl = new UrlAddress();
        $newUrl->setUrlEndpoint($urlEndpoint);
        $newUrl->setRealUrl($realUrl);
        $newUrl->setAutogenerated($autogenerated);

        $entityManager->persist($newUrl);

        $entityManager->flush();

        if($autogenerated){
            $created = "Hemos generado tu URL automáticamente con exito.";
        }else{
            $created = "Tu custom URL se ha creado con exito.";
        }

        return $this->forward('App\Controller\ShortenerController::index', [
            'created'  => $created,
            'endpoint' => "/$urlEndpoint",
            'autogenerated' => $autogenerated
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/redirection', name: 'redirection')]
    public function redirection(String $finalRedirection, ManagerRegistry $doctrine, Request $request): Response
    {   
        $repository = $doctrine->getRepository(UrlAddress::class);

        $url = $repository->findOneBy(['urlEndpoint'=> $finalRedirection]);

        if(!$url){
            // return new Response('No encontramos esa URL en nuestras bases de datos');
            // return $this->forward('App\Controller\ShortenerController::index', [
            //     'error' => 'No encontramos esa URL en nuestras bases de datos'
            // ]);
            $this->addFlash('error', 'No encontramos esa URL en nuestras bases de datos');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('shortener');
        }
        
        $finalUrl = $url->getRealUrl();
       
        if(str_split($finalUrl)[0] === 'h'){
            return $this->redirect($finalUrl);
        }else{
            return $this->redirect('http://'.$finalUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

- UrlAddres.php (Entity)

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UrlAddressRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UrlAddressRepository::class)]
class UrlAddress
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $urlEndpoint;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $realUrl;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'boolean')]
    private $autogenerated;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUrlEndpoint(): ?string
    {
        return $this->urlEndpoint;
    }

    public function setUrlEndpoint(string $urlEndpoint): self
    {
        $this->urlEndpoint = $urlEndpoint;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRealUrl(): ?string
    {
        return $this->realUrl;
    }

    public function setRealUrl(string $realUrl): self
    {
        $this->realUrl = $realUrl;

        return $this;
    }
```

The Apache virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.xyz
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.xyz
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.xyz/public
    <Directory /var/www/mydomain.xyz/public>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```